# Encoding md5 in a node compatible way

Tags: node.js, go, md5

I'm converting a node service to go. For this I need a compatible md5 hash (not for storing passwords!!) generator. However, in this example, I keep getting different results:

Node's `crypto` takes an encoding parameter when creating `md5`s.

```
> crypto.createHash("md5").update("1Editor’s notebook: Escaping temptation for turf145468066").digest("hex")
'c7c3210bd977b049f42c487b8c6d0463'
```

In golang: (test_encode.go)

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "testing"
)

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    const result = "c7c3210bd977b049f42c487b8c6d0463"

    stringToEncode := "1Editor’s notebook: Escaping temptation for turf145468066"
    hash := md5.Sum([]byte(stringToEncode))
    hashStr := hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])

    if hashStr != result {
        t.Error("Got", hashStr, "expected", result)
    }
}
```

Then `go test test_encode.go` results in:

```
--- FAIL: TestFoo (0.00s)
encode_test.go:17: Got c3804ddcc59fabc09f0ce2418b3a8335 expected c7c3210bd977b049f42c487b8c6d0463
FAIL
FAIL    command-line-arguments  0.006s
```

I've tracked it down to the `encoding` parameter of `crypto.update` in the node code. And the fact that the string as a `’` quote character in it. If I specify `"utf8"` it works.

```
crypto.createHash("md5").update("1Editor’s notebook: Escaping temptation for turf145468066", "utf8").digest("hex")
```

BUT: I can't change the node code, so the go code has to be compatible. Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: A go playground to demonstrate: https://play.golang.org/p/IUYGwGA_zi

Comment: Go does not support any charset besides UTF-8. And it should because it's the only one you should be using.

Comment: @TheHippo yeeeeeeah unfortunately the world is not as simple as that. Legacy systems and what not. Thanks for your input on the matter though...

Comment: After some digging there might be chance that you still get it working. It's not in stdlib but there are some packages dealing with encoding: Take a look at https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding and https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging in node and V8 I was able to conclude the following:

```
require("crypto").createHash("md5").update(inputString).digest("hex");
```

Is pretty dangerous, as not specifying a encodes the input string as "ASCII". Which, after a lot of digging, is the equivalent (verified on a large input set from my end):

```
// toNodeASCIIString converts a string to a byte of node compatible ASCII string
func toNodeASCIIString(inputString string) []byte {
    lengthOfString := utf8.RuneCountInString(string(inputString))
    stringAsRunes := []rune(inputString)

    bytes := make([]byte, lengthOfString)
    for i, r := range stringAsRunes {
        bytes[i] = byte(r % 256)
    }

    return bytes
}
```

What is basically does is mods by 256 and forgets a large part of the input string.

The node example above is pretty much the standard and copy-pasted-everywhere way to create MD5 hashes in node. I have not checked but I'm assuming this works the same for all other hashes (SHA1, SHA256, etc).

I would love to hear someones thoughts on why this is not huge security hole.

Comment: Seriously. You are right. Node hashing just uses the first byte of each unicode code point!? Yes, it does open up for more collisions, but it also makes any node-created hash incompatible with any other system as soon as the input string contains characters not part of Latin-1. Strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already noted: you must convert the UTF8 string to whatever encoding is used in your node application. This can be done with encoding packages such as:

`golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap`

```
isoString, err := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewEncoder().Bytes([]byte(stringToEncode))
```

Considering that the character `’` is not allowed in iso-8859-1, we can assume you have a different encoding. Now you just need to figure out which one!

And in worse case, you might have to use another package than `charmap`.